# Convert a string beginning with a point to its decimal value

Tags: c#, .net

How can I convert a string that start with a decimal point to its decimal value when current culture is set to id-ID in c#

```
if (SessionHelper.Culture == "id-ID")
    {

        objGuestInvoiceDetail.DPSTransactionFee = Convert.ToDecimal(objParameter.ParameterValue);
    }


//objParameter.ParameterValue contains value=".80"
```

Comment: You could prepend it with a 0.

Comment: Your question seems to be written in your title, while the text of your question itself doesn't show enough information of what the problem actually is and what you tried to solve it. Do you get any exception? Did you try searching the web for the exception message? What did you find and try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (SessionHelper.Culture == "id-ID")
    {

        objGuestInvoiceDetail.DPSTransactionFee = Convert.ToDecimal(String.Format("0{0}",objParameter.ParameterValue));
        //objGuestInvoiceDetail is ="0.80"
    }


//objParameter.ParameterValue contains value=".80"
```